# How to navigate between multiple pages in XAML C# using the dependency object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Consider a XAML app, that has multiple pages using menu items to go any one of these pages.

The best method referenced utilizes something like the following example,

```
NavigationService.GetNavigation(DependencyObject).Navigate("Check1_Page.xaml");
```

What is the Dependency Object? I get the following error when attempting to navigate the page using XAML like below:

```
<Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11.637,36.549,0,77.453" Width="116.42">
            <MenuItem Header="Check 1" Height="28.055" Width="116.42" ToolTip="Check stuff in 1." Click="MenuItem_Click_2"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Check 2" Height="28.055" Width="116.42" ToolTip="Check stuff in 2." Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
</Menu>
```

Using C# like below:

```
private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this).Navigate("Check1_Page.xaml");
        }
```

I am thinking using the `this` keyword, would be referencing the `object sender`, though am unsure. Essentially, am trying to do this for multiple pages on the main XAML page.

Exception occurs when using the `this` keyword, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is an example of the stack trace:

```
   at App.MainWindow.MenuItem_Click_1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\FileLocation\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 73
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at App.App.Main() in C:\FileLocation\App\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: `this` cannot be null. Ever if I'm not gravely mistaken. It references the instance of the class the called function is in. `sender` is a reference to the sending control (your `Button`) The NavigationService returned by GetNavigationService on the other hand would very likely be null if you didn't previously set that up.

Comment: Is this a WPF or UWP or Windows Phone or Windows 8 or Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: This would be WPF.